# keras: how to train input layer

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am trying to get the ideal input for a particular class of imagenet data. I am using keras inceptionv3 initialized with imagenet weights. I have also set a custom tensor which is random initialized as input. I have set all layers as non trainable except input. Here is the code:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.layers import Input
import keras
import keras.backend as K

# this could also be the output a different Keras model or layer
inp = K.random_uniform_variable(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), low=0, high=1) # Uniform distribution
# input_tensor = Input(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), tensor=inp)  # this assumes K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last'

model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=inp, weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
input_layer = model.layers[0]
input_layer.trainable = True
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(y=[0], batch_size=1, epochs=50, verbose=1)
```

after running the above script, the loss always remains the same 6.901. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The `inputLayer` is just a placeholder or tensor wrapper, there are no trainable parameters in this layer. If you use `model.summary()`, it will show that #parameters is 0.

```
    Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
=========================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 299, 299, 3)  0                                            
_________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 149, 149, 32) 864         input_1[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `Input` layer in keras is not trainable. it only passes through whatever value you pass to it. Since you set all other layers to trainable=False (hence no weights are updating) I guess thats the reason why your loss remains constant.

Comment: I tried the same in tensorflow, the loss slowly goes down and stays constant at 5.8 after 1000 steps or so. I believe there is a fundamental flaw here. I don't know if you're getting what im trying to do, im trying to get the best possible input for the network to predict the class 0 for imagenet...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like the `DeepDream` implementation. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb) in a jupyter notebook. When you want to do this, you have to use tensorflow instead of the high level keras API. Then you can calculate gradients with respect to your image and update it until you get your desired result. Typically you have to take care of scaling and so on. I think this might be explained in the jupyter notebook!